# What is wrong in my VUE code that doesn't show the upload result

Tags: javascript, vue.js, client-side

I made a component for uploading images. This component uploads images but **"if"** does not work! what is the problem? It should show the upload result after the uploading finished!
The component uploads files and images perfectly.
I should mention that I have used a template for the VUE/ASP.net core.

You can see the code at:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_9GCtqKltBV4ECbMghAU0jdb45YW1ncv/view?usp=sharing

```
<template>
    <h1>Uploading an Image!</h1>

    <p>This component demonstrates Uploading Image to server.</p>
    <p v-if="!uploadResult"><em>{{this.uploadResult}}</em></p>

    <div v-if="uploadResult">{{this.uploadResult}} </div>

    <div>
        <form>
            <!--<input type="text" value="" v-model="projectName" placeholder="please enter the project name." />-->
            <input type="file" v-on:change="getFile($event)" />
            <button v-on:click="submitForm($event)">Upload</button>
        </form>

    </div>

</template>
```

Comment: the `setTimeout(() => {  }, 3000);` part is to simulate the fetching (wait for 3 sec) because i don't have access to your API. you can ignore those two line and use back the fetch function. I updated the code and commented those 2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code in CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-agnesi-w5p9p?file=/src/App.vue

The problem is the `{{ this.uploadResult }}`, it should be `{{ uploadResult }}`.

```js
<p v-if="!uploadResult"><em>{{ uploadResult }}</em></p>
<div v-else>{{ uploadResult }}</div>
```

I changed a bit of your code to set `uploadResult = ""` instead of `" "` in the initial state and set the `this.uploadResult = "uploading"` before fetching.

```
this.uploadResult = "uploading...";

// fetch()xxxxx
const data = { fileName: "Test" };
this.uploadResult = "File " + data.fileName + " successfully uploaded.";
this.getList();
```